# Android Back button not the same action from Fragment and his activity

Tags: android, button, android-activity, fragment

I've got this :

MainActivity.java :

```
package activity;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import com.example.pierre.tan.R;

import adapter.FragmentDrawer;
import hotchemi.android.rate.AppRate;
import hotchemi.android.rate.OnClickButtonListener;
import model.Arrets;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener {

private Toolbar mToolbar;
private FragmentDrawer drawerFragment;
public static Arrets arrets = null;






@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    AppRate.with(this)
            .setInstallDays(5) // default 10, 0 means install day.
            .setLaunchTimes(10) // default 10
            .setRemindInterval(1) // default 1
            .setShowNeutralButton(true) // default true
            .setDebug(false) // default false
            .setOnClickButtonListener(new OnClickButtonListener() { // callback listener.
                @Override
                public void onClickButton(int which) {
                    Log.d(MainActivity.class.getName(), Integer.toString(which));
                }
            })
            .monitor();

    // Show a dialog if meets conditions
    AppRate.showRateDialogIfMeetsConditions(this);


    arrets = new Arrets();

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);



    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);


    View searchContainer = findViewById(R.id.search_container);




    drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
    drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), mToolbar);
    drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);
    drawerFragment.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);

    // display the first navigation drawer view on app launch
    displayView(0);



}




@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setMessage("Voulez-vous quitter l\'application ?")
            .setPositiveButton("oui", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }).setNegativeButton("non", null).show();




}

@Override
public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {
    displayView(position);
}

private void displayView(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.title_home);
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new ArretsFragment();
            title = "Arrets";
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new AboutFragment();
            title = "A propos";
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new SettingsFragment();
            title = "Paramètres";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        // set the toolbar title
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }
}
}
```

ANd i've got HomeFragment.java :

```
package activity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.pierre.tan.R;

import java.util.List;

import adapter.CustomListAdapter;
import model.Arrets;
import util.Spfav;


public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

ListView favoriteList;
Spfav sharedPreference;
List<Arrets> favorites;

Activity activity;
CustomListAdapter productListAdapter;

public HomeFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    activity = getActivity();
}


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


}





@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {






    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    View searchContainer = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.search_container);
    final EditText toolbarSearchView = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.search);
    ImageView searchClearButton = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.search_clear);
    searchClearButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            toolbarSearchView.setText("");
        }
    });
    searchContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);


    sharedPreference = new Spfav();
    favorites = sharedPreference.getFavorites(activity);

    if (favorites == null) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {

        if (favorites.size() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }


        favoriteList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
        if (favorites != null) {
            productListAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(activity, favorites);
            favoriteList.setAdapter(productListAdapter);
        }


        favoriteList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


                TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lieu);
                String text = textView.getText().toString();


                TextView textView2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.arret);
                String libelle = textView2.getText().toString();

                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), TempsActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("text", text);
                i.putExtra("libelle", libelle);
                startActivity(i);


            }
        });


        favoriteList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(
                    AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                ImageView button = (ImageView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.imgbtn_favorite);

                String tag = button.getTag().toString();

                    sharedPreference.removeFavorite(activity,
                            favorites.get(position));
                    button.setTag("grey");
                    button.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_heart_white);
                   favorites.remove(favorites.get(position));
                    Toast.makeText(
                            activity,
                            activity.getResources().getString(
                                    R.string.remove_favr),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                sharedPreference.saveFavorites(activity, favorites);

                productListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

 return true;
            }

        });

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    }

    return view;
}


public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
}


public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
}
}
```

And i don't know how to do this : When i'm in the fragment (just Homefragment) set a ne function to the back press and don't execute the function of the activity (who works for other fragments).

Sorry for my bad english and if someone can help me it would be very nice !

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your activity:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onkeydown");
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {

            //your code here

            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode,event);
    }
```

Fragments have their own `onBackPressed()` handler, which is called instead of activity's handler. This is done to return to previously shown fragment by pressing back for example.